# How to interact with child spwan using pexpect in a python script

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pexpect

I'm trying to create a child and send it a command in order for me no need to hit enter in my child window. It gets to the window but is like the child expects is not getting the return. Can someone explain how can I do it better?

I do this because I need the spawn to be in a new terminal window, this works ok.

```
child = pexpect.spawn ('gneome-terminal --windows --wait -- 'command'')
```

Then I try to get to interact with the child I just created by:

```
child.expect ('Return.*', timeout=None)

child.sendline('\r')

child.interact()

child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Comment: pexpect usually cannot interact with a GUI app unless that app is specially designed to support this.